# Is it possible to train YOLO - object detection model on FPGA?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, fpga, yolo, conv-neural-network

Training on images needs a lot of computations to derive at least a considerable amount of precision for object detection. As I studied on fully training of object detection models like YOLO, it is said that it takes from hours to days on GPU. 
    However, we are trying to implement a hardware accelerator for CNN training using FPGA for an object detection model like YOLO and we are doing it for the final year project in our university. Since we are trying to find out the feasibility of the project before moving further, any suggessions in this regard would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never really want to train on FPGAs or on similar "low cost" hardware. Training needs a lot more memory and a lot more computational power.

The common approach is to train the network normally on GPUs and then quantize it to whatever you need to let it run on the FPGA. Once this is done you can try to load the architecture and weights onto the FPGA.

I would assume just getting a single network architecture to run is challenging enough, so start with this and maybe then think about extending it so arbitrary architectures and be run.